# ansible commandline host pattern filter by inventory variables

Tags: ansible

I have an ansiblehosts.ini file that looks like this:

```
[mygroup]
server1 services='["web","app"]'
server2 services='["web"]'
server3 services='["app"]'
server4 services='["nfs"]'
```

I want to know if there is a way to use the ad hoc `ansible` command to act only on hosts in `mygroup` where `"web"` is in the host's `services`.

This works:

```
$ ansible 'mygroup:&server1:&server2' --list-hosts
  hosts (2):
    server1
    server2
```

But I want to do something like this, which obviously doesn't work:

```
$ ansible 'mygroup:&{{ "app" in services }}' --list-hosts
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: "web"
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: in
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: services
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: }}
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: {{
[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
  hosts (0):
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are reinventing the wheel. Use groups.

```
[web]
server1
server2

[app]
server1
server3

[nfs]
server4

[mygroup:children]
web
app
nfs
```

Then:

```
 ansible -i my_inventory.ini web --list-hosts
  hosts (2):
    server1
    server2
```

---

To go a bit further, I suspect you added the `services` variable for a role/playbook matching reason. You can very easily do the exact same thing with groups even if they do not all match to a service. For convenience, I'll use a all-in-one yaml inventory file for my example but you can translate back to ini if you wish of even separate vars in their own files. See [how to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

```yaml
---
all:
  # These vars will be applied to all hosts.
  vars:
    # This should list group names mapped to a particular service
    known_services:
      - web
      - app
      - nfs
    # This will be calculated for each host and will hold
    # groups it belongs to that match an entry in known_services
    services: "{{ group_names | intersect(known_services) }}"
  children:
    mygroup:
      children:
        web:
          hosts:
            server1:
            server2:
        app:
          hosts:
            server1:
            server3:
        nfs:
          hosts:
            server4:
```

Check it works with a simple debug:

```
$ ansible -i my_inventory.yml web -m debug -a var=services
server1 | SUCCESS => {
    "services": [
        "app",
        "web"
    ]
}
server2 | SUCCESS => {
    "services": [
        "web"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I really like your approach. Mapping groups to services is a cool idea. However, I am trying to use the inventory the Linux Admin uses and avoid having to have my own inventory. I don't want to add managing a host of inventory files (ha!) to my work load, esp when the Linux Admin already does that.